# Teamcity jmeter Performance Metrics Calculation: Check reference values

Tags: jmeter, teamcity

I have setup TeamCity with JMeter plugin. Under Build Configuration -> Build Features, I selected 'Performance metrics calculation'. I can see the build log is cumulative with previous execution results. However, when checking for failure conditions in the build log for 404 or 500 status code, it always fails if at least one previous instance has these response codes. Without this, the build always says Pass even if there are couple of requests that fail with error codes.

Under 'Check reference values', is it possible to set reference values to check the metrics against responsecode for errors? The only available options are 'Average', '90% line' and 'Max'. Any insight into how I can add options to select and search for error response codes?

Screenshots attached for reference

Thank you.

[TeamCity JMeter Performance Metrics Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrXwZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is [open source](https://github.com/jtorgan/jmeter_plugin) so theoretically you should be able to add required metric to check.

As a workaround I can suggest using [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to check response codes. If you need to test only "200" status code - it will be the matter of only one assertion (same level as HTTP Request samplers).

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more details on conditionally failing JMeter requests

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. 
Below are the options I tried but with no luck: 
1. Included Response Assertion (response code) within the script - no Assertion checks in build feature - Build always PASS even with 404 or 500 codes
2. Response Assertion within the script - Assertion checks in build feature - Build always FAIL even if all the responses return 200
3. Failure conditions - checking for code=404 in the build log - Build always FAIL if build history has errors from past runs 

-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true -n -t /<User>/jmeter/Test.jmx -l Tes4.jtl

Same issue without assertion option